# Git: How to fetch a pull request for testing

Tags: git, github, pull-request

I have been having trouble grabbing a pull request.  Here is my command line attempt at the pull request code:

```
$ git fetch upstream pull/3/head:testbranch
Password for 'http://MyAccount@git.MyGit.com':
fatal: Couldn't find remote ref pull/3/head
Unexpected end of command stream
```

We are using an origin repo and an upstream repo.

Pull requests go to upstream and origin is just under my name, I would like to pull down a request (#3) for review.  However any time I try to grab a pull it gives me the same error even if I change from upstream to origin.

What would be causing this issue? After I grab the code I would like to put it in a branch and basically take over work on it (a hand off) so I don't need access to the person's repo that made the pull request, just the content, and I am set up as an approver for the pull request itself already

Comment: The `http://MyAccount@git.MyGit.com` part seems weird. Is the pull request on GitHub, or somewhere else?

Comment: Actually, `git pull origin pull/29/head` worked for me [on this repo](https://github.com/thameera/vimv). Current path was the local copy of said repo.

Answer (score 9):

Looking at the output it seems that either the PR is closed or the PR does not exist.

**NOTE:**  Please commit your code before doing this as if you might have updated the code which will not be present anywhere then you might be in trouble.

The ideal way to test a PR is this way:

```
git fetch upstream pull/{PR-NUMBER}/head:test-branch-name
git checkout master
git merge test-branch-name
```

**NOTE:** If you find out that the code was bad and want to trace back to the previous commit then use this command:

`git reset --hard HEAD@{1}`

Hope it helps!

Comment: Note that `upstream` is a name returned by `git remote -v`. It may be `origin`. But in many situations, such as when you don't push directly but send PRs yourself, it's advisable to create the `upstream` remote.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried using the `git pull` command to pull down the remote branch?  You said you want to put the changes in some new branch?  For the sake of this answer, let's call it `newbranch`

First, create the new branch locally:

```
git checkout -b newbranch
```

Then, pull down the changes from the upstream testbranch.  The following assumes that you are working with a remote called `upstream` with changes in a branch called `testbranch`:

```
git pull . upstream/testbranch
```

And now you will have created a new branch called `newbranch` containing the changes in upstream/testbranch.

Comment: OP wants to fetch a pull request from GitHub, not just any usual branch from a remote.

Comment: Correct, that is the exact wording in the question, but perhaps OP asked for the `pull request` but really wanted the branch with the changes themselves for local review.  The `pull request` itself is an artifact of the git host, and cannot be pulled down the way that the changesets themselves can.

Comment: Yeah I was looking for how to get a pull request.  So what you are saying is IF I had access to that other person's repo I could do a pull on the feature branch they used to make the pull request?

Comment: A pull request is not an object stored in a git repository.  A pull request is an action performed ON a git repository.  Before github became popular, and even still today on the Linux Kernel Mailing List, pull requests are sent in email form.

Comment: No, I was suggesting that you pull FROM that person's repo (using read-only access) into your local repository so that you can continue working on top of his changes.  I may have misunderstood your question, but I thought that's what you wanted to do.

Comment: I thought to do it from the pull request because that was what i had immediate access to, but if your suggestion operates the same way then I can try to do that

Comment: No I wasn't able to figure out how to do it the correct command line way without getting an error.  so what I wound up doing was copying each file individually into a new branch.  luckily there weren't that many files.  I know if I knew the command line way of doing it it would have taken a tenth of the time but finding that answer was taking way too long :( thanks for all your help though!

Comment: Now I don't know if I should mark this resolved or not here :\

Comment: If you feel like the answer sufficiently answers your question, then you should upvote and accept it.  Regardless of whether you decide to accept the answer or not, you still have the option to upvote it and give out some rep points ;-)

Answer (score 1):

Install GitHub CLI tools via:

```bash
brew install gh
```

Then, using the PR number from the PR page on GitHub next to the title (has a # sign next to it, e.g, `#1234`), check it out by running the command:

```
gh pr checkout 1234
```

You'll now be on that PR in your editor, and can test locally or look at the line changes in the "Source Control" tab (VS Code for example).

Answer (score 0):

[Reference example Pull Request](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9WdCC.png)

This is pretty straightforward.

First, you need to check your repo remotes using the command.

```
git remote -v
```

For the purpose of this example, let's assume your remote is named "origin". Next, you need to retrieve the exact branch name for the pull request as depicted in the sample image.

Finally, you can now checkout the PR using the remote and branch name with the command

```
git checkout origin/feature/respect-user-corenode
```

Hope that helps.